# Navigation overlaps elements when wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of inline-blocks which I want to wrap when the browser window is shrunken.  They look like this:

[nav element 1] [nav element 2] [nav element 3] [nav element 4]

**This is a {h1} header.**

When the browser is resized, I want them to wrap, which they do.  But they overwrite the header on the next line:

[nav element 1] [nav element 2] [nav element 3]

[nav element 4]**eader.**

I've tried separating the header with paragraphs and linebreaks.  Nope.
I've tried putting a "clear:both" on the {h1} style.  Nope.
I've tried putting a {div} around the {h1} with a "display:block" and/or a "clear:both".  Nope.

I want the page content to move down when the nav bar wraps.

Any hints?

My code and its results can be seen at criv.com/test

**EDIT**

```css
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FF0000;
    border:2px solid black;
    clear:both;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
.nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:88px;
    height:50px;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#008000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-width:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:visited {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav a:hover, a:active {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav a#here {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:white;
}
ul.subnav {
    background-color:#009000;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid #009000;
    width:618px;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
    top:72px;
    left:220px;
}
ul.subnav li {
    display:block;
    width:123px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#009000;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
ul.subnav a {
    display:block;
    width:123px;
    height:18px;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size:75%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#009000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.subnav a:visited {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
ul.subnav a:hover, a:active {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
ul.subnav a#here {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:white;
}
.note {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
.text {
    background-color:white;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    color:#008000;
    width:80%;
    left:10%;
}
.text a:link {
    color:#008000;
}
.text a:visited {
    color:#999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href="list.html">2014 peony&nbsp;list</a>
    <a href="bloom.html">bloom calendar</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">photo gallery</a>
    <a href="howto.html">peony<br />how-to's</a>
    <a href="tales.html">peony<br />tales</a>
    <a href="visit.html"> <br />visit</a>
    <span class="clearfix"><a href="contact.html">contact/ order</a></span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="notreally"><h1>peonies of the coos riviera</h1></div>
<span class="text">
    Just above the Connecticut River in New Hampshire's Coos County,
    more than a hundred varieties of herbaceous peonies, tree peonies,
    and intersectional-hybrid peonies bloom from late May to early July.
    <p>The display garden has closed for the season.  To order peonies for fall planting, 
        email <a href="mailto:peonies@criv.com">peonies@criv.com</a>, or phone 603.837.9800.</p>
    <p>Review <a href="now.html"><b>the 2014 bloom season</b></a> in pictures!</p>
</span>
```

Comment: can you wrap all the nav elemtns and add class .clearfix . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/.

Comment: Please show your css and markup.

Comment: or you can add clearfix to the last element

Comment: Why show code that doesn't work?  Please show me code that makes this happen.

Comment: You can see the code at criv.com/test/index.html and criv.com/test/crivstyle.css

Comment: I couldn't get the code quoted in the right way for this forum interface--it wouldn't take it.  I thought you asked for code just to prove I tried.  If good code is posted, then it will make sense.

Comment: How do I use the clearfix solution?  I've seen all the CSS for it in about 100 web pages, but not once have I seen the HTML on how to use it.

Comment: How about YOU take the code from criv and manually put a '>' in front of all 200 lines of code and also rewrite every tag so the triangles don't get eaten.  Shouldn't take more than a few days.

Comment: Just remove `position: absolute;` from `.nav`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute from it. If you want nav to push 1px to top then you can use `margin-top:-1px`

Here is working code.

```css
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#FF0000;
    border:2px solid black;
    clear:both;
}
.nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
.nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:88px;
    height:50px;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#008000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-width:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:visited {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav a:hover, a:active {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.nav a#here {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:white;
}
ul.subnav {
    background-color:#009000;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid #009000;
    width:618px;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
    top:72px;
    left:220px;
}
ul.subnav li {
    display:block;
    width:123px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#009000;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
ul.subnav a {
    display:block;
    width:123px;
    height:18px;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size:75%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#009000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    border-width:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.subnav a:visited {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
ul.subnav a:hover, a:active {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
ul.subnav a#here {
    color:#008000;
    background-color:white;
}
.note {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
.text {
    background-color:white;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Arial, Sans-serif;
    color:#008000;
    width:80%;
    left:10%;
}
.text a:link {
    color:#008000;
}
.text a:visited {
    color:#999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href="list.html">2014 peony&nbsp;list</a>
    <a href="bloom.html">bloom calendar</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">photo gallery</a>
    <a href="howto.html">peony<br />how-to's</a>
    <a href="tales.html">peony<br />tales</a>
    <a href="visit.html"> <br />visit</a>
    <span class="clearfix"><a href="contact.html">contact/ order</a></span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="notreally"><h1>peonies of the coos riviera</h1></div>
<span class="text">
    Just above the Connecticut River in New Hampshire's Coos County,
    more than a hundred varieties of herbaceous peonies, tree peonies,
    and intersectional-hybrid peonies bloom from late May to early July.
    <p>The display garden has closed for the season.  To order peonies for fall planting, 
        email <a href="mailto:peonies@criv.com">peonies@criv.com</a>, or phone 603.837.9800.</p>
    <p>Review <a href="now.html"><b>the 2014 bloom season</b></a> in pictures!</p>
</span>
```